# Find an eigenvector of M corresponding to eigenvalue k

Tags: matrices, eigenfunctions

It is given that $M - kI$=
 \begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\1&\pi\end{bmatrix}

And I know that for $M$ (which is 2 x 2 matrix), there are two unique eigenvalues such that one of them is $k$.

FYI, I don't have any other info on $a_{11}$ and $a_{12}$.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Since $k$ is an eigenvalue of $M$, $M - kI$ is singular. So that, we have $a_{12} = a_{11}\pi$ and $a_{11}$ is arbitrary. Now, can you find an eigenvector?

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick response! I was thinking of using det(M-kI) = 0. which gives what you answered. But I am kinda lost as all a being arbitrary for the first row.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** If $k$ is an eigenvalue, the rows of $M-kI$ are linearly dependent. Since $M-kI$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix, this means they are proportional.

**Alternate solution** Let $v\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix}$ be the corresponding eigenvector. Then
$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\1& \pi \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix}=(M-kI)v=Mv-kV=0$$

Therefore,
$$a_{11}a+a_{12}b=0 \\
a + \pi b=0 $$

Just solve the second equation.

Comment: The rows are linearly dependent.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Ty, fixed.

Comment: just wondering since k is an eigenvalue, such that Mv = kv. (using the definition from textbook "A first course in linear algebra"). Are rows linearly independent for M - kI? Thanks again!

Comment: @mathrock1453 $Mv=kV \Leftrightarrow (M-kI)v=0$. This means that the corresponding system has non-trivial solution.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Are we able to find a specific eigenvalues to this? thanks again both of you.

Comment: Can you provide what is the next step, because I got a_{11} = 1 and a_{12} to be π

Comment: Also I was wondering why on my practice midterm, it tells me "there are two unique eigenvalues such that one of them is k.". Thanks again!